# Beanstalk error on deploying new app version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a beanstalk single instance app running with a PostgreSQL database. Nothing custom, all created via beanstalk. I haven't tweaked any security group or anything. Suddenly, I'm starting to get this error when I upload a new app version via AWS console-

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:1 validation error detected:
> Value '[AWS::RDS::DBInstance, AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate,
> AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress, AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup,
> AWS::EC2::EIP, AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition,
> AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle, AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup,
> AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup, AWS:EC2::SecurityGroupIngress]' at
> 'typeNameList' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy
> constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 204, Member
> must have length greater than or equal to 10, Member must satisfy
> regular expression pattern:
> [A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}::[A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}::[A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}(::MODULE){0,1}]

The same app bundle, uploaded via same mechanism used to work fine until last week. I understand that some resource's name is invalid, but I can't make which one's. Its strange since I've not tweaked with resources created by EBS. I did one thing though - connected the RDS with EC2. That's all, but it was working fine last week even with that.

Any idea what could be the error?